# Ubuntu 14.04.5 TL-WN822N V4 driver

Tags: drivers, usb

I've been trying to install drivers for my wireless adapter, but it didn't work. I tried TP link original driver but it only supports 3.16.0-30-generic kernel.

`$ lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b354 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd UVC 1.00 device HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2357:0108  
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c051 Logitech, Inc. G3 (MX518) Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please edit and add details about what you already tried. Most likely you will need to undone so...

Comment: well i work for this 5 days really dont remember nothing now

Comment: I would consider reinstalling Ubuntu, full update and test again. If not fixed then ask again.

Comment: when i was first open it isnt work why i want to reinstall my system _

Comment: I said I would consider it, not telling you to. But here's the problem: You probably made a mess already and diagnosing it may now require a back and forth which simply put isn't compatible with the Q&A format of AskUbuntu. You may try posting at the Ubuntu Forums.

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem too. Although I'm running elementaryOS loki instead of Ubuntu. Did you ever find a solution for this? I've created another [thread](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8882/how-to-install-drivers-for-tp-link-wn822n-v4-wireless-usb-adapter) and was hoping maybe someone here can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this problem by looking at [How to install tp link WN822N to ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832087/how-to-install-tp-link-wn822n-to-ubuntu)

This method successfully installed the adapter in Lubuntu 16.04. It appears that you have to re-install the driver each time the kernel is updated, which is quite often, but if you follow the instructions at the end and have retained the driver file, it is quite easy.

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to [flag](/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other once you [earned 15 reputation](/help/whats-reputation). Don't forget to vote for the answer(s) there that you found useful!