# How to install TP link WN822N on Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, usb, adapter

When I type in `lsusb`, the device appears as ID 2357:0108

That's right, it's blank at the end. I've updated the usb ids yet its always blank. I have no idea what to install to make this thing work. I'm dual booting on mac osx

Comment: `lsusb` doesn't give the chipset?

Comment: no it just comes up as blank

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest that, with a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

You wireless should now be working.

When Update Manager installs a later kernel version, also known as linux-image, after the required reboot, then recompile:

```
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

Please retain the file and these instructions for that time.

Comment: They have an official driver: http://static.tp-link.com/res/down/soft/TL-WN822N(EU)_V4_160315_Linux.zip

Comment: @AndroidDev The driver is for older kernels:  2.6~3.16

Comment: This works! However, now it doesn't recognize the chipset when I type in lsusb; it just shows a blank

Comment: Sorry about `lsusb`; I believe that information is coded by the device manufacturer, not the operating system. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: http://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Is "git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver" same as " wget https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver"? What is git clone and how does it work?

Comment: GIT clone clones a git, i.e., it copies all the contents and folder structure from the remote git site to your local drive.

Comment: The `wget` method you suggest gets an HTML file; not the required driver files.

Comment: I've put the files from the GitHub repo on a USB stick, copied the files over to a folder on my ubuntu machine, and accessed the folder from the terminal. After `make`, `make install` & `modprobe` I'm still not seeing the wireless signal searching for network. Thoughts?

Comment: Oh Sweet, I figured it out: When you download from GitHub the branch name is appended to the file name, so `rtl8192eu-linux-driver` becomes `rtl8192eu-linux-driver-master`. After `mv`ing the folder back to its original name (`rtl8192eu-linux-driver`) it works like a charm. Thanks so much for this!