# tl-wn822n v4 wireless adapter needs unplug and replug to work

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I am new to Ubuntu, using 16.04.

I installed the tl-wn822n v4 adapter following [How to install TP link WN822N on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832087/how-to-install-tp-link-wn822n-on-ubuntu)
but the problem is that after I restart the computer, the wifi adapter is no longer recognised.

I have to run the following commands to make it work (if I don't want to unplug/replug).

```
sudo modprobe -r 8192eu
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

I added the commands to `/etc/rc.local` but it still does not work after a restart.  As of now, the only way is to run the commands manually or physically unplug/replug the adapter.

Is there a better way to fix it?

Comment: What happens if you run only `sudo modprobe 8192eu`?

Comment: nothing happens.  -r is needed first.

Comment: Can you uninstall that driver by `sudo make uninstall` from the source directory and install this deb https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtl8192eu-dkms_4.4_all.deb

Comment: Just tried uninstall and installed the rtl8192eu-dkms_4.4_all.deb.  Restarted the computer and it's working!  Just to be sure, I did a shutdown and startup of the computer.....not working.  I still have to unplug/replug for it to work.

Comment: I updated the /etc/rc.local with the following and it finally works.

modprobe -r 8192eu
modprobe 8192eu
sleep 5