# installing WN822N V4 driver for RPI 3

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

i have spent countless hours searching the web, trying all recomended solutions to installing the driver for the TP-Link WN822N wireless usb adapter. I am running ubuntu mate on RPI 3, all is up to date too.

uname -r output : 4.9.31-v7+

lsusb output:

```
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2357:0108  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

the id is 2357:0108 for the usb adapter.

I have already tried installing the 8192eu realtek driver, without success.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/832087/how-to-install-tp-link-wn822n-on-ubuntu

Comment: @chili555 i have tried those instructions and this is the output i get.



rtl8192eu-linux-driver# make
make ARCH=armv7l CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.9.31-v7+/build M=/home/walachewaka/rtl8192eu-linux-driver  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.9.31-v7+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:1335: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2

Comment: The missing `build`directory indicates that you have not installed linux-headers matching your kernel; in your case, 4.9.31-v7. Please find and install them and try again.

Comment: PS - I suspect this is not Ubuntu and I suspect we can help you no further.

Comment: sorry for the delay, was off to work, and I am running Ubuntu Mate.