# Linux/Ubuntu wireless adapter for desktop

Tags: wireless, adapter

I have acquired a desktop with no internet connection. It has linux and ubuntu, neither of which I am familiar with. What wireless adapter works with these? I have no ethernet access. I need something easy to install. I have no idea about codes or anything else I've seen on some forums.

Comment: Which desktop, which ethernet, which Linux, which Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: Just get a USB WiFi adapter. I've couple with realtek chip. Those are fairly well supported.

Comment: It's not going to get a better answer than this question got so please don't bogus close vote this question as primarily opinion based as frequently happens here to questions having authoritative answers.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you get a USB wireless device. However, there are several, mostly Broadcoms and a few Mediateks, that won't work no matter what we try.

You can get some guidance as to known working devices here:https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2309068 and here: https://www.thinkpenguin.com/catalog/wireless-networking-gnulinux

Answer (score 0):

TP Link TL-WN822N V4.0 Linux USB Wireless Adapter

Chipset= WI1 chip1: Realtek RTL8192EU

https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
Drivers for the rtl8192eu chipset for wireless adapters (D-Link DWA-131 rev E1 included!)

$ lsusb

Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2357:0108

1)Install git:

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install git

2)Copy a file of the driver into your computer:

$ git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

3)Navigate to the directory of the driver

$ cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver

4)Build the driver software and install:

$ make

$ sudo make install

... then if it is still not working, continues with the following...

$ sudo modprobe 8192eu

$ reboot

6)Make a new wifi connection with Realtek 802.11n WLAN Adapter

Note: If your the wifi adapter connection doesnt show up after rebooting, try turning off the secure boot option to enable the third party driver to work

[How to install TP link WN822N on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832087/how-to-install-tp-link-wn822n-on-ubuntu)
When Update Manager installs a later kernel version, also known as linux-image, after the required reboot, then recompile:

$ cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver

$ make clean

$ make

$ sudo make install

$ sudo modprobe 8192eu

$ rfkill list all; lshw -c net

Warning: ... The driver is for older kernels: 2.6~3.16
www.tp-link.com/us/download/TL-WN822N.html
official driver: static.tp-link.com/res/down/