# Cannot load rtl8192eu drivers in Lib/Modules to use TP-Link WN822N usb adapter

Tags: drivers, wireless, adapter

I have a wireless TP-Link WN822N v4 usb wireless adapter I want to use in Ubuntu. Drivers rtl8192eu are not found in  Lib/Modules after `make install`.

Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
$ uname -r 4.15.0-29-generic

I followed the instructions from an older post on this forum:
[How to install TP link WN822N on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832087/how-to-install-tp-link-wn822n-on-ubuntu)

```
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

Everything ran successfully, except for the last command: `sudo modprobe 8192eu`.

> modprobe: FATAL: Module 8192eu not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic

All the 8192eu drivers are in my Home directory after the `cd` and `make install` . Here are 2 examples:

```
CC      /home/tomx2/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/8192eu.mod.o
LD [M]  /home/tomx2/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/8192eu.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic'
```

I am unable to to copy/paste 8192eu drivers in Lib/Modules, without permission.

> How can I get 8192eu drivers into Lib/Modules?

I am a new Ubuntu user. Any help will be appreciated.

**EDITED BY OP: 08/06/2018:**

**@Jeremy31**
As per your request lsusb is listed below. 
I can connect to my hotspot, but I'm not sure the the rtl8192eu.ko driver is being used.
I suspect a default driver is being accessed.
Getting only 1 band during connection. Very slow.
I do not see 8192eu.ko driver in Lib/Module (see listing below).
The wireless usb adapter TP-Link WN822N does not light up/blink but will disconect from hotspot when I unplug.

Is there a way I can get rtl8192eu driver to be used?

Thanks.

**LSUSB**

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0813 VIA Labs, Inc.

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:5682 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216f Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth

Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0951:16a1 Kingston Technology

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0108

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc.

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

**All Drivers named 8192 in Lib/Module/modules-order listed.**
kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192u/r8192u_usb.ko
kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192e/rtllib.ko
kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192e/rtllib_crypt_ccmp.ko
kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192e/rtllib_crypt_tkip.ko
kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192e/rtllib_crypt_wep.ko
kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192e/rtl8192e/r8192e_pci.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192ce/rtl8192ce.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192cu/rtl8192cu.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192se/rtl8192se.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192de/rtl8192de.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723ae/rtl8723ae.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/btcoexist/btcoexist.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8821ae/rtl8821ae.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192ee/rtl8192ee.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8xxxu/rtl8xxxu.ko

**iwconfig**
wlx18a6f712cbe1  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"BayBreeze Hotel"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 2A:A4:3C:4F:4B:1E
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

**ifconfig**
wlx18a6f712cbe1: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.10.201  netmask 255.0.0.0  broadcast 10.255.255.255
        inet6 fe80::bf41:879e:2afb:9bc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 18:a6:f7:12:cb:e1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 15487  bytes 4469574 (4.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1882  bytes 206547 (206.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

**EDITED BY OP Tomx2: 08/06/2018  11:17:00 PM:**

**sudo lsmod | grep cfg** 
cfg80211              622592  2 wl,mac80211

2 References to mac80211 in Lib/Modules.

kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko

kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mac80211_hwsim.ko

**Edited 08/10/2018 New info. This is the OP:**

I was able to resolve the “Modprobe Fatal Module 8192eu not found in Lib/Modules” error.
Needed to install app: ***libelf-dev***. This allowed a clean Make/Install.
When I launch the internet using TL-link Wn822N as my USB interface, the connection is extremely slow.

Only one Band and the wireless interface does not light up.
Below are 2 output (linux) commands for your review.
One shows 8192eu driver the other shows rtlxxxu.

(Q) Do I need to Modprobe another driver?
    Can anybody help?

**sudo lsmod | grep cfg**

cfg80211              622592  3 wl,mac80211,**8192eu**

**sudo lshw -c network**

*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:2.3
       logical name: wlx18a6f712cbe1
       serial: 18:a6:f7:12:cb:e1
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=**rtl8xxxu** driverversion=4.15.0-29-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.10.201 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEE

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `lsusb`  Actually just try a reboot

Comment: Check `lsmod | grep cfg` and see what modules it shows

Comment: sudo lsmod | grep cfg cfg80211 622592 2 wl,mac80211

2 References to mac80211 in Lib/Modules.

kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko

kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mac80211_hwsim.ko

Answer (score 0):

Solution is [there](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes/blob/master/README.md). Whereas announced as DEPRECATED, the method id still valid.
Do not forget to blacklist the old driver(last step of the howto) which was most probably my case.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed TP-Links driver source and that does work in Ubuntu 18.04

https://github.com/noud/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux

Comment: Good job with that driver... However I would not recommend anyone, to download, compile and `insmod` a kernel driver from (sorry for that) a un-trusted source. Also you downloaded the drivers from tp-link.com (which are under a MIT licence) and changed it to GPL.

Comment: Thank you about a job well done. I am not sure about your license remark. If i look at TP-Link's [support gpl-code](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/gpl-code/) and [GPL License Terms.pdf](https://static.tp-link.com/resources/document/GPL%20License%20Terms.pdf) it self is talking about GPL Version 3.

Comment: You say it is risk to download from an un-trusted source and it most times sure is. But one can compare the initial commit being the exact same content as TP-Links archive plus a .gitignore file. All commits i made afterward are readable and easily checked.