# Can't install rtl8192eu-linux-driver on UBUNTU 18.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, compiling, dkms

I am using UBUNTU 18.10 and I had problem with TL-WN822n v5 driver in UBUNTU and Kali (4.19.0-kali5-amd64)

The problem is driver=rtl8xxxu so I found a driver in this page :
https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

and installed the driver on Kali and it worked perfectly fine but when I wanted to install it on my ubuntu, after I ran the `sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0;` I got this error :

```
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=4.18.0-25-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8192eu: 1.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.18.0-25-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192eu/1.0/build/make.log for more information.
```

and This is my Log file (`/var/lib/dkms/rtl8192eu/1.0/build/make.log`) :

```
DKMS make.log for rtl8192eu-1.0 for kernel 4.18.0-25-generic (x86_64)
Sun Jul  7 13:35:02 +0430 2019
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.18.0-25-generic/build 
M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8192eu/1.0/build  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-25-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192eu/1.0/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mlittle-endian’; did you mean ‘-fconvert=little-endian’?
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:325:/var/lib/dkms/rtl8192eu/1.0/build/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1534:_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtl8192eu/1.0/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-25-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:1710: modules] Error 2
```

What's the problem ??

Comment: That might be a compiling issue with arm64

Comment: How can i fix it ?? My ubuntu and kali both are amd64 , but the kali works fine @Jeremy31

Comment: type `arch` in terminal in ubuntu

Comment: The output is : x86_64 @Jeremy31

Comment: Install Ubuntu 18.04 and use the mange driver, then file a bug against package linux for rtl8xxxu having bad signal strength

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the driver that works fine for me in here : https://askubuntu.com/a/832092/929631

As it's mentioned, run these commands to compile the driver:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make
sudo make install
```

After this, you need to block the previous driver `rtl8xxxu` with this command :

```
echo "blacklist rtl8xxxu" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf;
```

And force RTL8192EU Driver to be active from boot:

```
echo -e "8192eu\n\nloop" | sudo tee /etc/modules;
```

Newer versions of Ubuntu has weird plugging/replugging issue (Check #94). This includes weird idling issues, To fix this:

```
echo "options 8192eu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/8192eu.conf;
```

Update changes to Grub & initramfs:

```
sudo update-grub; sudo update-initramfs -u;
```

Reboot system to load new changes from newly generated initramfs:

```
systemctl reboot -i;
```

And check if the right driver is installed or not :

```
sudo lshw -c network;
```

You should see the line`driver=8192eu`

Comment: Perfect answer. Saved hours

Comment: I get this error during the make `*** /lib/modules/4.19.0-17-amd64/build: No such file or directory.`. How would I fix that?

Comment: Nvm I had to run `sudo apt-get install linux-headers- \`uname -r\` `

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully installed N300 Wi-Fi USB adapter MW300UH on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with this driver using this https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver