# TP-Link TL-WN823N v3 wifi dongle not detected

Tags: 16.04, tp-link

I'm trying to install drivers for TP-Link TL-WN823N v3 wifi dongle on Ubuntu 16.04, without success.
At present it's not being detected at all.

Edit: It seems to be Bus 002 Device 005: ID 2357:0109

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 2357:0109
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 148f:2573 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2501/RT2573 Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0644:0200 TEAC Corp. All-In-One Multi-Card Reader CA200/B/S
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1058:25a2 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1058:25a1 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bc2:2321 Seagate RSS LLC Expansion Portable
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: See the solution. https://askubuntu.com/a/1157387/167850

Comment: Thank you, such a swift reply and the answer in the suggested post is very comprehensive.
It worked 100%.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install rtl8192eu-linux-driver on UBUNTU 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156519/cant-install-rtl8192eu-linux-driver-on-ubuntu-18-10)

Comment: That solution you sent https://askubuntu.com/a/1157387/167850 fixed it. Thanks.