# Usb wifi dropped out / rtl8192eu-linux-driver on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, usb

The wifi device TP-LINK TL-WN823N was previously working, as in previous thread: [TP-Link TL-WN823N v3 wifi dongle not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208060/tp-link-tl-wn823n-v3-wifi-dongle-not-detected)
But now it is not detected again.
I re-followed the instructions in the previous thread but it is still not detected.
What next?

`lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 148f:2573 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2501/RT2573 Wireless Adapter
Bus 02 Device 005: ID 2357:0109  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0644:0200 TEAC Corp. All-In-One Multi-Card Reader CA200/B/S
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1058:25a1 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1058:25a2 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bc2:2321 Seagate RSS LLC Expansion Portable
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

`lsmod | grep cfg; mokutil --sb-state`

(after installing mokutil):

```
cfg80211              630784  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
EFI variables are not supported on this system
```

As I recall, Bus 02 Device 005: ID 2357:0109
is the one which had the functioning wifi usb before.

Comment: Use https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver  Ubuntu 18.10 is no longer supported

Answer (score 2):

If you have internet access by any other means (wired or through USB tethering), you can installed the RTL8192EU drivers from [Mange's GitHub repo](https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver). Here are the steps as described on the GitHub page:

**Building and installing using DKMS**

1. Install DKMS and other required tools:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
   ```
2. Clone this repository and change your directory to cloned path.

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
   cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
   ```
3. Add the driver to DKMS. This will copy the source to a system directory so that it can used to rebuild the module on kernel upgrades.

   ```
   sudo dkms add .
   ```
4. Build and install the driver.

   ```
   sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
   ```
5. Distributions based on Debian & Ubuntu have RTL8XXXU driver present & running in kernelspace. To use our RTL8192EU driver, we need to blacklist RTL8XXXU.

   ```
   echo "blacklist rtl8xxxu" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf
   ```
6. Force RTL8192EU Driver to be active from boot.

   ```
   echo -e "8192eu\n\nloop" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
   ```
7. Newer versions of Ubuntu has weird plugging/replugging issue (Check #94). This includes weird idling issues, To fix this:

   ```
   echo "options 8192eu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/8192eu.conf
   ```
8. Update changes to Grub & initramfs

   ```
   sudo update-grub; sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
9. Reboot system to load new changes from newly generated initramfs.

   ```
   systemctl reboot -i
   ```
10. After the reboot, you can check that your kernel has loaded the right module:

    ```
    sudo lshw -c network
    ```

You should see the line `driver=8192eu`

Comment: Only steps 1-5 are needed