# Wifi issue on linux

Tags: 18.04, wireless, 20.04

I'm using a TL-WN821N TP-Link wifi adapter. I have good internet connection when using Windows, but unfortunately I have a bad internet connection in Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04. I tried numerous ways to fix it, but no there has been no improvement.

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045e:00cb Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse v2.0
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:07b9 Microsoft Corp. Wired Keyboard 200
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:0107 TP-Link TL-WN821N Version 5 RTL8192EU
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0924:42d5 Xerox Phaser 3020
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-28-generic/build M=/home/oleg/rtl8192eu-linux-driver  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-28-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:147: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
  CC [M]  /home/oleg/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_cmd.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /home/oleg/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1719: /home/oleg/rtl8192eu-linux-driver] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-28-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:1700: modules] Error 2
```

```
sudo make install
install -p -m 644 8192eu.ko  /lib/modules/5.4.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install: cannot stat '8192eu.ko': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:1706: install] Error 1
```

I think I managed to install the driver, I used another thread, but internet speed not increased. Is there something else I can do?

Comment: Could you describe what is exactly wrong with the connection?

Comment: When I make a speed test it shows me a speed twice slower compared to windows. and in ubuntu 20.04 it's not connecting to router at all.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command. There is a ton of hardware revisions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install rtl8192eu-linux-driver on UBUNTU 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156519/cant-install-rtl8192eu-linux-driver-on-ubuntu-18-10)

Comment: This thread asks to run few commands: make, and sudo make install. there are a lot of error lines that I receive, not sure if it suppose to like this. I edited the question with the output

Comment: Any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

## Poor IPv6 performance?

Check whether it could be an IPv6 related problem. You can disable IPv6 with

```
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

If this helps, you can try to set IPv4 precedence over IPv6 by uncommenting `#precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100` in the file `/etc/gai.conf`.

## Power Management?

Look whether turning off wifi power management could be a least the reason for poor wifi performance:

Edit the file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

and set `wifi.powersave = 3` to `wifi.powersave = 2`.

You can check the current power management state with

```
$ iwconfig 2> /dev/null | grep 'Power Management'
```

## Kernel issue?

Some users experience better network performance by using a newer kernel from [the mainline PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).
But please keep in mind that a newer kernel might have other issues (i.e. in combination with proprietary drivers like NVidia) and you have to keep track of updates etc.
There are also scripts to maintain mainline kernels like [`ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh`](https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh#ubuntu-mainline-kernelsh).

*If* it is fixed with a newer kernel, chances are high, that a bugfix for this issue will be backported. So you should find and track this issue. Therefore you could switch to the stable kernel once this issue has been fixed.

**PS:** You can also add the corresponding Launchpad issue to this thread. This way others can track this issue as well.