# Realktek driver rtl8192eu stops working after update to new kernel 5.19

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, realtek, realtek-wireless

Wifi stopped working after kernel upgrade to 5.19 on Ubuntu 22.04. After upgrading my kernel, I usually run

```
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

based on this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832087/how-to-install-tp-link-wn822n-on-ubuntu/832092#832092), and that sort of restarts the driver and the wifi starts working again. But, this time, I am getting some errors

```
xander@xander:~/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/rtl8192eu-linux-driver$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.19.0-051900-generic/build M=/home/xander/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/rtl8192eu-linux-driver  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-051900-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-5ubuntu1) 11.3.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
  CC [M]  /home/xander/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/xander/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/include/osdep_service.h:45,
                 from /home/xander/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/xander/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/xander/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_cmd.c: In function ‘rtw_cmd_thread’:
/home/xander/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/include/osdep_service_linux.h:165:31: error: implicit declaration of function ‘complete_and_exit’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  165 |         #define thread_exit() complete_and_exit(NULL, 0)
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/xander/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:759:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘thread_exit’
  759 |         thread_exit();
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/xander/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:761:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
  761 | }
      | ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:249: /home/xander/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1849: /home/xander/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/rtl8192eu-linux-driver] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-051900-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:1700: modules] Error 2
```

Is this based on the new networking updates in 5.19? Is there a way to get the wifi working again?

Here is some more info:

```
xander@xander:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2357:0109 TP-Link TL-WN823N v2/v3 [Realtek RTL8192EU]
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8086:0808 Intel Corp. USB PnP Sound Device
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone 5/5C/5S/6/SE
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and

```
xander@xander:~$ sudo modprobe rtl8xxxu && sudo dmesg | grep -i rtl
[sudo] password for xander: 
[  156.327410] usb 3-4: rtl8192eu_parse_efuse: dumping efuse (0x200 bytes):
[  156.327466] usb 3-4: RTL8192EU rev B (SMIC) 2T2R, TX queues 3, WiFi=1, BT=0, GPS=0, HI PA=0
[  156.327468] usb 3-4: RTL8192EU MAC: 7c:c2:c6:09:79:0f
[  156.327470] usb 3-4: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin
[  157.136472] usb 3-4: rtl8192eu_rx_iqk_path_b: Path B RX IQK failed!
[  157.161142] usb 3-4: rtl8192eu_rx_iqk_path_b: Path B RX IQK failed!
[  157.224386] usb 3-4: rtl8192eu_rx_iqk_path_b: Path B RX IQK failed!
[  157.248480] usb 3-4: rtl8192eu_rx_iqk_path_b: Path B RX IQK failed!
[  157.253666] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8xxxu
[  157.266091] rtl8xxxu 3-4:1.0 wlx7cc2c609790f: renamed from wlan0
```

after downgrading the kernel to 5.16.20 I get:

```
xander@xander:~$ sudo dmesg | grep wlx
[sudo] password for xander: 
[    4.654790] rtl8192eu 3-4:1.0 wlx7cc2c609790f: renamed from wlan0
[    9.618667] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx7cc2c609790f: link becomes ready
```

On the 5.19 the output of this command is blank.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?  as there is no upgrade to the 5.19 kernel?   (*Ubuntu 22.04.1 was the recent upgrade and the first upgraded kernel doesn't arrive till 22.04.2 which is still months into the future*)  Are you using Pop OS or some other OS?

Comment: I am using 22.04 LTS, but manually upgraded the kernel via uktools.

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 and Kernel: 5.19.0-051900-generic

Comment: Kernel 5.19 is very new. Do you have an updated source code for the driver with support for 5.19? Isn't there a built in rtl8192eu module?

Comment: I am doing the same on 5.18 and getting the same make error. I am just using the old driver, which is the only one available. Is it possible I need to upgrade gcc to version 11.03, to match the one used with the kernel?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal commands: `lsusb` and `sudo modprobe rtl8xxxu && sudo dmesg | grep -i rtl`

Comment: Ok, added, thanks.

Comment: It looks like your wireless started right up, yes? Is rtl8xxxu blacklisted? Does it scan and see networks? `nmcli device wifi list` No need to post the results, just tell us if it sees networks or if there is some error or warning.

Comment: In settings, wifi has disappeared as an option, so I can't scan or see networks. I did not blacklist.

Comment: Let's see, in an edit: `sudo dmesg | grep wlx`

Comment: I just downgraded the kernel to 5.16.20, and now the dkms installs and works. Do you think the driver just isn't compatible with the newest kernel? I added the output. I can try and reboot into the new kernel and provide the output from that?

Comment: The output is blank in 5.19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the driver you are using is not compatible with the 5.19 kernel.

You have some options:

1. Patch the driver to make it compatible.
2. Wait till somebody else does p.1.
3. Use a compatible kernel.

Comment: I used 5.16.20 and it worked. 5.18 did not. I think the version of gcc used to compile the driver is not the same as that for kernel 5.18 and 5.19. Is there a good wifi adapter for Ubuntu which is very compatible with new kernel's etc? Or would any adapter have this problem in this setting?